# Подключение к Unix серверу с PostgreSQL через libssh

Tags: c++, visual-studio, postgresql, ssh

Имеется сервер с Ubuntu. На нем установлена PostgreSQL. Пишу GUI приложение на C++ для удаленного управления БД. Для того, чтобы подключаться по SSH, в Visual Studio была установлена библиотека libssh. Проблема заключается в том, что C++ приложение не может подключиться к аккаунту psql. К самому серверу подключение проходит, можно зайти в dev аккаунт postgres, а в аккаунт управления БД не подключается.

Код установления сессии для соединения:

```
ssh_session my_ssh_session;
  int rc, auth;

  int port = 22;
  my_ssh_session = ssh_new();
  ssh_options_set(my_ssh_session, SSH_OPTIONS_HOST, "188.120.*** . ***");
  ssh_options_set(my_ssh_session, SSH_OPTIONS_USER, "root");
  ssh_options_set(my_ssh_session, SSH_OPTIONS_PORT, &port);
  rc = ssh_connect(my_ssh_session);
  if (rc != SSH_OK)
  {
    cout << stderr << " Error connecting to host:" << ssh_get_error(my_ssh_session);
    exit(-1);
  }
  else if (rc == SSH_OK)
    cout << "Connection complete" << endl;;
  const char *password = "mypass";
  auth = ssh_userauth_password(my_ssh_session, NULL, password);
  if (auth != SSH_AUTH_SUCCESS) {
    cout << stderr << " Error to auth" << ssh_get_error(my_ssh_session);
  }
  if (auth == SSH_AUTH_SUCCESS) {
    cout << "Auth complete" << endl;
 }
```

Далее устанавливается канал для обмена данными и смена пользователя с root на postgres:

```
int postgres_log(ssh_session my_ssh_session) {

  ssh_channel channel;
  int rc;
  char buffer[256];
  int nbytes;
  channel = ssh_channel_new(my_ssh_session);
  if (channel == NULL)
    return SSH_ERROR;
  rc = ssh_channel_open_session(channel);
  if (rc != SSH_OK)
  {
    ssh_channel_free(channel);
    return rc;
  }
  rc = ssh_channel_request_exec(channel, "su - postgres");
  if (rc != SSH_OK) {
    ssh_channel_close(channel);
    ssh_channel_free(channel);
    return rc;
  }
}
```

Переключение проходит. Далее пытаюсь перейти на пользователя psql аналогичной функцией, только вместо

```
rc = ssh_channel_request_exec(channel, "su - postgres");
```

использую

```
rc = ssh_channel_request_exec(channel, "psql");
```

Но переключение не происходит. В этом вся проблема.

Comment: в чём угодно. без минимального примера и сообщений об ошибках вопрос подлежит закрытию. [mcve]

Comment: Ошибок никаких не выводится. Просто не получается перейти на аккаунт управления БД, типа psql или созданного пользователя.

Comment: *Ошибок никаких не выводится* — этого просто не может быть. изучите внимательнее все соответствующие логи.

Comment: Нашел только предупреждение на функцию postgres_log - "Значение возвращается не при всех путях выполнения."

Comment: Ответь на несколько наводящих/уточняющих вопросов: Как ты понимаешь, что делает `ssh_channel_request_exec()` вообще и `ssh_channel_request_exec(channel, "su - postgres")` в частности? Как именно ты работаешь с каналом после этого (код в точности)? И по всей концепции в целом: не лучше ли просто пробросить порт через ssh тунель и создать нормальное подключение к базе на удалённый localhost?

Comment: ssh_channel_request_exec() отправляет на сервер команду, которую последний выполняет.
Это первая работа с ssh, по этому могу допускать ошибки. 
"пробросить порт через ssh тунель и создать нормальное подключение к базе на удалённый localhost" - не до конца понял концепцию. Можете подробнее объяснить?

Comment: Кажется допер. Вы предлагаете создать подключение через libssh и с помощью libpq организовать подключение к БД?